# How can i change the default homepage (at port 8080) in glassfish3.1 server to my own page

Tags: glassfish-3

I want to change the default homepage (which appears on typing "http://myserverip:8080") and redirect it to my another webpage i have developed using Netbeans 7.1 .
Please Help..

Comment: in which technology you are developing ? If in JSP Servlet you can change in the <welcome-file-list> tag in Web.xml file...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that your Netbeans project is a valid java web application.

**Option 1:**

You can set one of your webapps as default. This can be done with the admin console:

Configuration --> sever-config --> virtual-server --> server

Then select your default web application from the drop-down menu. If your webserver port is 8080, you can start your application now by:

http://hostname:8080

instead of http://hostname:8080/webapp

**Option 2:**

You could also deploy your default webapp to "/" instead of "/webapp" but I think the first option is more flexible.

Comment: Thanks Matt.
Its working now.

OK in case i want to just use some other simple html page without using any IDE like Netbeans, then what should i do ?

Comment: In first case IDE doesnt come in picture... You just need a access of Glassfish's Admin console...i.e. http://hostname:4848/

Comment: You can find the default glassfish index.html in <gf_install>/domains/domain1/docroot.  If you replace that file you can put whatever you want.  docroot is like apache DocumentRoot and is a good place for some simple static html, but not for high-traffic access.